# Hosting WCF service and WebAPI in the same WebApplication

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

I've implemented an OData service using ASP.NET WebAPI. I also have some existing web methods in a seperate WCF project which is hosted in an ASP.NET Web Application.

By copying some bits of web config around and copying a couple of code files I've managed to get the WCF methods hosted in the WebAPI project.

Everything seems to be working but I've got a nagging doubt I'm doing something horribly wrong that's going to break when I least expect it.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your anticipated call volume. The only problem I can think of with this is that incoming WCF requests will be serviced from the same dispatcher thread pool as the OData service. This makes it more likely that you will suffer availability based issues on either endpoint.